# Surrogate Composite Key in MVC 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, models

In ASP.NET MVC 5, I have the following models:

JoinModel.cs

```
// Many-to-many join model
public class JoinModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ModelAID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ModelBID { get; set; }

    public virtual ModelA ModelA { get; set; }
    public virtual ModelB ModelB { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ValueModel> Values{ get; set; }
}
```

ValueModel:

```
public class ValueModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // public int JoinModelID { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public virtual JoinModel JoinModel { get; set; }
}
```

I want change it in such a way that I have an `ID` property in JoinModel, so I can use JoinModelID in ValueModel. I also want to keep `ModelAID` and `ModelBID` as composite surrogate/candidate keys (just for uniqueness) and `ID` as primary key. Is there a way to do so?

Note: making all three ID, ModelAID and ModelBID as composite ID is *not* what I want.